# How to redirect in .htaccess? (multilanguage)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, lang

I have a multilingual website and. Htaccess, which displays all the pages.

I want to redirect (using code 301) asks with `RewriteEngine`. For example:

```
site.com?lang=ru => site.com (remove `lang=ru` - Russian only)
site.com/news.html?lang=ru => site.com/news.html

site.com/home.html => site.com (remove `home.html` - only on the main page)
site.com/home.html?lang=ua => site.com/?lang=ua

site.com/rev.html?lang=ua&start=0 => site.com/rev.html?lang=ua (If start = 0, then remove `start=0`)
site.com/rev.html?lang=ua&start=27 => site.com/rev.html?start=27&lang=ua (should be conversely)

and so on many ...
```

*I have very little experience of the redirect. You can help me.* How to prepare your htaccess file for Apache to meet this criterion? What to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing `lang=ru`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?lang=ru(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

Removing the `home.html`

```
RewriteRule ^home.html$ / [L,R=301]
```

Removing `start=0`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?start=0(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

Swapping `start=##` and a `lang=##`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)lang=(.+)&start=([0-9]+)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1start=%3&lang=%2%4 [L,R=301]
```